# Expanding / Retracting Menu Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to expand/retract a menu bar from the left-side of the screen.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu-button').on("click",
    function(){
      $('.menu').css("left","0");
      $('.menu-button').addClass("clicked");
    }
  );

  $('.menu-button clicked').on("click",
    function(){
      $('.menu').css("left","-168");
      $('.menu-button').removeClass("clicked");
    }
  );

});
```

The menu bar is expanding, but not retracting back. I think this code makes sense- but apparently not. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
$('.menu-button clicked')
```

to

```
$('.menu-button.clicked')
```

But then the problem is when you click again. Both clicks will happen. So you add and remove the class. To fix that you could do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu-button').on("click", function(){
      if($('.menu-button').hasClass('clicked')) {
          $(this).removeClass("clicked");
          $('.menu').css("left","-168");
      } else {
          $(this).addClass("clicked");
          $('.menu').css("left","0");
      }
  });
});
```

But the most simple would be to use `toggleClass` like so:

```
$('.menu-button').on("click", function(){
    $('.menu').toggleClass( "clicked" );
    $(this).toggleClass( "clicked" );
});
```

and if possible you should always change CSS via CSS and not use javascript inline-styles.. so now with `.toggleClass` you toggle the class and change your css. Just adding colored borders here to give you an idea but you change your styles how ever you need them.

```
.menu {
    /* add your styles here */
    left: -168px;
    border: solid 2px red;
}

.menu.clicked {
    /* add your styles here */
    left: 0;
    border: solid 2px green;
}

.menu-button {
    /* add your styles here */
    border: solid 2px orange;
}

.menu-button.clicked {
    /* add your styles here */
    border: solid 2px lime;
}
```

Comment: @JakeMartinez can you share your HTML? Where is the `.menu-button` inside the `.menu`

Comment: .menu-button is not within .menu - it is outside and fixed to the top-right corner of the page.

Comment: @JakeMartinez see answer now, I've updated. Is it working now?